# How to access user identity in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server

In C# 3.0 ASP.NET I'm composing a CMS and I want to compose a SQL query that accesses my user identity.

In my master page I have a `SqlDataSource` that I want to compose a SQL query that returns an ID from a table

### EDIT

OK, look at this example: (this is in `Page_Load`)

```
sqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = String.Format("select PageGroupID from users where Username = {0};", Page.User.Identity.Name);
```

But it doesn't work :(

Please help me!

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? Are you using a gridview or some bound countrol?

Answer (score 3):

It won't work because you're constructing an invalid SQL string using string.format
Try this, instead.

```
sqlDataSource1.SelectCommand =
     String.Format("select PageGroupID from users where Username = '{0}';", 
     Page.User.Identity.Name);
```

Then when it works, go and read about **SQL injection** and why constructing SQL strings like this is **A BAD IDEA**.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this [article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1186509.aspx/1) - it should help you get the right value from `Page.User.Identity.Name` and then you can go from there by ensuring your **database** has **matching** values based on what it's returning.

Answer (score 0):

To understand difference try this;

```
string.Format("<br />Page.User.Identity: {0} " +  "<br />Request.LogonUserIdentity: {1}",
Page.User.Identity.Name, Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name);
```

Use Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.